# How to trigger AWS Device farm tests from Azure devops

Tags: azure-pipelines, aws-device-farm, cicd, aws-toolkit

I have an Azure CI-CD build for a mobile app, which when it finishes building, I wish it to connect to my AWS Device Farm and trigger a suite of tests on the app produced.

Is there something in AWS that I can setup so I can access it through some AWS API from my Azure build? And also on the Azure Devops side, how can I do that? I have installed "[AWS Toolkit for Azure DevOps](https://aws.amazon.com/vsts/)" but not sure where to go from there (if that toolkit is even needed).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, in Azure DevOps Marketplace, you can install the [AWS ToolKit for Azure DevOps](https://aws.amazon.com/vsts/) like I did. From there, the task you need to add to your build is called "[AWS CLI](https://aws.amazon.com/cli/)" and it will allow you to specify the authentication, command, subcommand, and options for the action you wish to perform. Nothing needs to be done on AWS as the AWS CLI interacts with the different API endpoints for your services.